# Good regular expression for capturing data inside single quotes but only if it prefixed with something?

Tags: regex, go, regex-group

I have a massive amount of text I just need the contents of whats inside the single quotes (excluding the single quotes).

for example, here's a cutdown version of what I am searching.

```
output line from channel: [2021-11-14 15:59:20] config='954'!
output line from channel: [2021-11-14 15:59:21] DEBUG: job_name='test' disabled=true
output line from channel: [2021-11-14 15:59:25] DEBUG: job_id='a185' configsized
```

and I would like to return

```
a185
```

The regular expression I have so far is this, but it returns the jobid='' - as well as the data i required. I tried to use a capture group and I thought you could delete it?

My regex skills are old and out of touch lol :-)

```
(job_id=)'[^']*'
```

Note that the line has to have `DEBUG` on it somewhere to match everything.

Comment: Capture what you need (want to retain) instead.

Comment: You may want to add the applicable language/environment you are going to use your regex with.

Comment: Updated the environment, its golang. Added to main question. Thanks.

Comment: Right now, I am just testing it inside of a regular expression tester (online)

Comment: You can use `(?<=job_id=')[^']+` [regex online link](https://regexr.com/69ge1)

Comment: thanks @decpk, that seems to work! Can I also say that the line has to have DEBUG on it somewhere to match everything. DEBUG might not come in exactly the same place ?

I tried this but it didn't work ```(?<=DEBUG)(?<=job_id=')[^']+```

Can you create an answer and I can accept etc.

Comment: The capture group should be around the part between the single quotes `job_id='([^']*)'` See https://regex101.com/r/1sslNH/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
DEBUG.*job_id='([^']*)'
```

and get the Group 1  value. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AnqR8e/1/). *Details*:

- `DEBUG` - a `DEBUG` string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `job_id='` - a `job_id='` string
- `([^']*)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars other than `'`
- `'` -  a `'` char.

See the [Go demo online](https://play.golang.org/p/N416wsFK-R-):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    markdownRegex := regexp.MustCompile(`DEBUG.*job_id='([^']*)'`)
    results := markdownRegex.FindStringSubmatch(`output line from channel: [2021-11-14 15:59:25] DEBUG: job_id='a185' configsized`)
    fmt.Printf("%q", results[1])
}
// => "a185"
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Yep the look behind isn't supported by the standard library from go. So it would have been nice to use look behind. This is the correct answer for GO and standard library.